# Style guide / optimal way to layout web.config & app.config for ongoing support

Tags: .net, layout, web-config, app-config, organization

Config files have grown so complex that some have suggested that they are [their own programming language.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648246/at-what-point-does-a-config-file-become-a-programming-language)  If I were to take this analogy further, it would make sense to have some consistencies when editing the file.

I was going to limit this question to WCF, which is very sensitive to the smallest configuration change, but think other sections (web.config) would benefit from a structure as well.

Given that VS2010 will handle the indentation of the file, what other standards are applicable when updating a config file?  Some ideas I came up with :

- Sort `<config sections>` alphabetically
- The name identifier within `<config sections/>` should be pushed to the left

Alternatively

- Group identifiers and `config sections` by similar function

I'm guessing the guidance may vary slightly between specialties (Web vs WCF vs identity model) but I'd appreciate hearing your own perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always (until something forces the opposite) sort everything alphabetically (sections, nodes, subnodes), except sections' declaration, which have to going first.